# Take in escaped input in Ruby command line app

Tags: ruby, bash, escaping, backslash

I'm writing a Ruby command line application in which the user has to enter a "format string" (much like Date.strptime/strftime's strings).

I tried taking them in as arguments to the command, eg

```
> torque "%A\n%d\n%i, %u"
```

but it seems that bash actually removes all backslashes from input before it can be processed (plus a lot of trouble with spaces). I also tried the [highline gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/highline), which has some more advanced input options, but that automatically escapes backslashes "\" -> "\\" and provides no alternate options.

My current solution is to do a find-and-replace: "\\n" -> "\n". This would take care of the problem, but it also seems hacky and awful.

I could have users write the string in a text file (complicated for the user) or treat some other character, like "&&", as a newline (still complicated for the user).

What is the best way for users to input escaped characters on the command line?

(UPDATE: I checked the documentation for strptime/strftime, and the format strings for those functions replace newline characters with "%n", tabs with "%t", etc. So for now I'm doing that, but any other suggestions are welcome)

Comment: "I could have users write the string in a text file (complicated for the user) or treat some other character, like "&&", as a newline (still complicated for the user)."  And writing this "%A\n%d\n%i, %u" as a parameter is not complicated?

Comment: True, but it's not as bad as regex :/ I give users a bunch of example output and places to test the format string, and I don't want things to be MORE complicated than they have to be

Comment: Your title is misleading. You want escaped input, not unescaped input.

Comment: I think you're right. Bit new at this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is using single quotes instead of double quotes.

Thus:

```
> torque '%A\n%d\n%i, %u'
```

Any string quoted in single quotes `'eg.'` is does not go through any expansions and is used `as is`.

More details can be found in the `Quoting` section of `man bash`.

From `man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Comment: It doesn't look like that works. Bash seems to remove all backslashes before I get the string whether it's in single/double/no quotes... I get (> torque 'asdf \n asdf') => "asdf n asdf"

Comment: @NcAdams As per my understanding, that is impossible. See `man bash` section on `Quoting`.

Comment: @NcAdams bash quoting works for me, perhaps you're doing something to interpret escapes in the ruby domain. `ruby -e 'puts ARGV[0].inspect' 'foo \n bar'` => `"foo \\n bar"`

Answer (score 0):

```
p eval("\"#{gets.chomp}\"")
```

Example use:

```
\n\b    # Input by the user from the keyboard
"\n\b"  # Value from the script

%A\n%d\n%i, %u   # Input by the user from the keyboard
"%A\n%d\n%i, %u" # Value from the script
```

Comment: This seems hackier than my proposed solutions :/ But it would work! Thanks